# How do I resolve the source Instagram post (or shortcode) from a direct link to image resource?

Tags: security, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Facebook has (or at least used to have) a neat naming scheme for their image resources where you could look up a profile from the middle part of the filename. As an example `279365521459373` in `367377237_279365521459373_92792065027978136_n.jpg` would let you find the author by visiting `https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=279365521459373`. My thought process is that Instagram is basically just Facebook with a different frontend, and that's at least half-way true, since Instagram images also follow this naming scheme.

My problem is that while Instagram *does* follow the naming scheme, the middle part of the filename doesn't seem to correspond to anything useful regarding either the post or the profile. If I use a recent LinusTechTips post as an example, I can figure out the following properties:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Post URL | `https://www.instagram.com/p/Cv0PT9eLitq/` |
| Image link (signed) | `https://scontent-cph2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/367377237_279365521459373_92792065027978136_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_p1080x1080&_nc_ht=scontent-cph2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=YCxMjQWen2YAX80UWH1&edm=AP_V10EBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfBI3f1NTuCUF` |
| Supposed profile id from filename | `279365521459373` |
| Shortcode | `Cv0PT9eLitq` |
| Media ID | `3167223780320619370` |
| Profile handle | `linustech` |
| Profile ID | `231599715` |

Nothing in the request URL, query string or response headers look remotely like the users actual Profile ID. I can't find any documentation on any endpoints / graph api tricks that allow me to do this reverse lookup of resource uri to either shortcode/mediaid or handle/profileid, as expected. I get that Instagram would like to (at least appear to) protect the users privacy, so I didn't expect to find much. However, I don't think I'm the first or last developer to look for a way to do this.
I've tried to look around on Google & DDG, but most questions seem to relate to getting the direct link from the post (which is trivial). I poked around in the Graph API docs, but I didn't find much. The oembed endpoints were completely barren, so that's a dead end too.
I also found an old blog post on how Instagram names their files ([Sharding & IDs at Instagram](https://instagram-engineering.com/sharding-ids-at-instagram-1cf5a71e5a5c))

Note that the solution doesn't have to be related to the middle part of the filename, I just want to resolve the post from the direct link.

**TL;DR:** Have link to jpg, want link to post.